# ComboBox SelectedText, why is it not switching to the SelectedText item?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, combobox

Question:

My combobox (Me.cbHomeDrive) doesn't get properly initialized if I use

```
Me.cbHomeDrive.SelectedText = "E:"
```

On Form_Load:

```
For i As Integer = AscW("C"c) To AscW("Z"c) Step 1
      Me.cbHomeDrive.Items.Add(New ComboBoxItem(ChrW(i) + ":"))
Next

Me.cbHomeDrive.SelectedIndex = 26 - 3
Me.cbHomeDrive.Enabled = False
```

With class ComboBoxItem being:

```
Public Class ComboBoxItem
    Public Text As String
    Public ID As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String)
        Text = strText
        ID = strText
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strID As String)
        Text = strText
        ID = strID
    End Sub


    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function
End Class
```

Now If I do

```
Me.cbHomeDrive.SelectedText = "E:"
```

right after

```
Me.cbHomeDrive.Enabled = False
```

Then nothing happens, and the combobox shows as Z:.

If instead of

```
Me.cbHomeDrive.SelectedText = "E:"
```

I use

```
SetComboBoxToTextIndex(Me.cbHomeDrive, "E:")
```

with

```
' WTF '
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx '
Sub SetComboBoxToTextIndex(ByVal cbThisComboBox As ComboBox, ByVal strItemText As String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To cbThisComboBox.Items.Count - 1 Step 1
        If StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(cbThisComboBox.Items(i).ToString(), strItemText) Then
            cbThisComboBox.SelectedIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Then it sets the correct selected item (E:).

Why does it not work with Me.cbHomeDrive.SelectedText = "E:"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the `SelectedText` property is, refer to the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

The `SelectedText` property *is not* the item from the list of items, it's the portion of an editable combobox that is selected, as if you were doing a copy/paste type of selection.

Your `SetComboBoxToTextIndex` method is the proper way to find and select an item in the list.  Aternatively, if your ComboBoxItem properly implements `Equals`, you can find the appropriate instance and set the `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Crap, you're right. That's what happens when "one" only reads the first ambiguous paragraph. It gets clearer when one also reads all the rest. Very ambiguous property.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Nah, I upvoted you too. I usually give the green tick to the first one, but in this case, CodingGorilla's answer was simply a lot better expressed.

Answer (score 5):

This code will do what you want easily. ;)

```
myList.SelectedIndex = myList.FindString(myText);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ComboBox.SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx) is equivalent to [`TextBox.SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectedtext.aspx), i.e. it specifies the text that is selected inside the textbox of a combobox. It doesn't change the SelectedItem, because it has a completely different semantic.

Answer (score 0):

If the item is of type object You can use **SelectedItem**

```
ComBaudRate.ValueMember = "Value";
ComBaudRate.DisplayMember = "Text";
string[] baudValues = {"1200", "2400", "4800", "9600", "19200", "38400", "57600", "115200"};
ComBaudRate.Items.Clear();
for(var idx = 0; idx < baudValues.Length; idx++)
{
     ComBaudRate.Items.Add(new { Text = baudValues[idx], Value = baudValues[idx] });
}    
ComBaudRate.SelectedItem = new { Text = "19200", Value = "19200" };
```